# How can I add a partition to /etc/fstab on 22.04

Tags: 22.04

When there are multiple partitions on the disk blkid returns UUID and PARTUUID Of course UUID can't be a mount point when it only represents the drive not the partition Should I use PARTUUID in /etc/fstab ?

Answer (score 2):

`UUID` is a fileystem poperty stored in the file systems superblock.

`PARTUUID` is a GPT feature and is a unique identifier for a partition, the `PARTUUID` is stored in the Partition table.

You can use whatever you want in `/etc/fstab`, `UUID` or `PARTUUID`, that's up to you. You can also use `LABEL` (file system label, stored in superblock) or `PARTLABEL` (partition label stored in GPT partition table) to identify partitions in `fstab`. I prefer to use `LABEL` or `PARTLABEL` because of better readability in fstab. If you want to use `LABEL` or `PARTLABEL`, they need to be defined first using appropriate tools, for example `gparted`.

The `UUID` is not a mountpoint, it is just a unique identifier. The mountpoint is a directory, the directory name itself can of course be the same as the `UUID`.

If you have more than one partition on a disk or more than one disk, each partition must have it's own unique identifier, wether you use `UUID`, `PARTUUID`, `LABEL` or `PARTLABEL`. It's the duty of the system adminstrator (probably you) to ensure the uniqueness of the partition identifiers. For example cloning of partitions leads to a situation where you have two partitions with the same identifier which would cause some problems and you'd have to change the identifiers of one of the partitions, the original or the clone.

Comment: The machine hangs after displaying 9 errors each on a new line, here I'll delimit them with comments: Failed to start Samba NMB Daemon, Failed to start Samba SMB Daemon, Failed to start Elasticsearch, Failed to start Network Name Resolution, Failed to start Network Name Resolution, Failed to start Network Name Resolution, Failed to start DW Agent, Failed to start Network Name Resolution, Failed to start Network Name Resolution

Comment: @fugeeohu You may want to ask a new question about that. It doesn't sound as if it has to do with `fstab`. But if you think it has to do with `fstab`, include the output of `cat /etc/fstab` in your new question. Be as detailed as possible.

Comment: I think it's looking for something not found since I changed things around

Comment: @fugeeohu You need to [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and describe your problem precisely (error messages, things you changed around), so the community may be able to help you. Your problem is not going to be solved in the comment section under this answer here. You were probbly asking the wrong thing in the question above. There are not even any details about the problem you have. So please ask a new question, thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499992/ubuntu-20-04-machine-hangs-on-startup-with-failed-to-start-services-messages

Comment: I overcame that problem by mounting a partition in /etc/fstab with the name of the mount point I knew it must have been looking for As an added note, after that I needed to replace 'remount-ro' with 'defaults' for btrfs filesystem type since the former didn't apply, which is why my machine wouldn't boot